# How to find out which dtype tensors are accepted by a given inbuilt tensorflow function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a tensorflow project using complex numbers, so I frequently need to apply inbuilt functions on complex inputs. So how can I check which tensorflow functions accept a complex argument as input?

For example, 
when I try to use the function tf.math.scalar_mul() as follows -

```
...
self.scalar = tf.Variable(3, tf.int16)
output = tf.math.scalar_mul(x, self.scalar)
...
```

it produces the following error -

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype complex64: 'Tensor("fourier__conv2d_5/mul:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 17), dtype=complex64)'
```

I feel it is probably due to tf.math.scalar_mul() not accepting complex input. Am I correct, or if not what could be the mistake. (I am trying to use tf functions instead of basic python functions as I think it might give benefit while running on GPU)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this out, but the result will be given in terms of ops and kernels, which do not map exactly to higher-level Python functions. In case you are not familiar with the architecture of TensorFlow, it is built around the concept of "ops", which are just formal descriptions of an operation with tensors (e.g. the op "Add" takes two values and outputs a third value). A TensorFlow computation graph is made of interconnected op nodes. Ops do not implement any logic by themselves, they just specify the name and the attributes of the operation, including which data types to which it can be applied. The implementation of the ops is given by kernels, which are the actual pieces of code that do the work. A single op can have many registered kernels that operate with different data types and/or different devices (CPU, GPU).

TensorFlow keeps "registries" with all of this information, stored as different [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) messages. Although it is not part of the public API, you can actually query these registries to get the list of operations or kernels that meet certain criteria. For example, this is how you can get all the ops that operate with some complex type:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_ops_with_dtypes(dtypes):
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
    valid_ops = []
    dtype_enums = set(dtype.as_datatype_enum for dtype in dtypes)
    reg_ops = ops.op_def_registry.get_registered_ops()
    for op in reg_ops.values():
        for attr in op.attr:
            if (attr.type == 'type' and
                any(t in dtype_enums for t in attr.allowed_values.list.type)):
                valid_ops.append(op)
                break
    # Sort by name for convenience
    return sorted(valid_ops, key=lambda op: op.name)

complex_dtypes = [tf.complex64, tf.complex128]
complex_ops = get_ops_with_dtypes(complex_dtypes)

# Print one op
print(complex_ops[0])
# name: "AccumulateNV2"
# input_arg {
#   name: "inputs"
#   type_attr: "T"
#   number_attr: "N"
# }
# output_arg {
#   name: "sum"
#   type_attr: "T"
# }
# attr {
#   name: "N"
#   type: "int"
#   has_minimum: true
#   minimum: 1
# }
# attr {
#   name: "T"
#   type: "type"
#   allowed_values {
#     list {
#       type: DT_FLOAT
#       type: DT_DOUBLE
#       type: DT_INT32
#       type: DT_UINT8
#       type: DT_INT16
#       type: DT_INT8
#       type: DT_COMPLEX64
#       type: DT_INT64
#       type: DT_QINT8
#       type: DT_QUINT8
#       type: DT_QINT32
#       type: DT_BFLOAT16
#       type: DT_UINT16
#       type: DT_COMPLEX128
#       type: DT_HALF
#       type: DT_UINT32
#       type: DT_UINT64
#     }
#   }
# }
# attr {
#   name: "shape"
#   type: "shape"
# }
# is_aggregate: true
# is_commutative: true

# Print op names
print(*(op.name for op in complex_ops), sep='\n')
# AccumulateNV2
# AccumulatorApplyGradient
# AccumulatorTakeGradient
# Acos
# Acosh
# Add
# AddN
# AddV2
# Angle
# ApplyAdaMax
# ...
```

Here the elements in `complex_ops` are [`OpDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.proto) messages that you can inspect to find out the exact structure of the op. In this case, `get_ops_with_dtypes` simply returns every op that has one of the given data types among its `type` attributes, so the complex value could apply to one of the inputs or the output.

Another alternative would be to look directly for the kernels that work with the data types you are interested in. Kernels are stored as [`KernelDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.proto) messages that do not have all the information about the op, but they have for example information about the device they can run on, so you can also query for kernels that support a specific device.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_kernels_with_dtypes(dtypes, device_type=None):
    from tensorflow.python.framework import kernels
    valid_kernels = []
    dtype_enums = set(dtype.as_datatype_enum for dtype in dtypes)
    reg_kernels = kernels.get_all_registered_kernels()
    for kernel in reg_kernels.kernel:
        if device_type and kernel.device_type != device_type:
            continue
        for const in kernel.constraint:
            if any(t in dtype_enums for t in const.allowed_values.list.type):
                valid_kernels.append(kernel)
                break
    # Sort by name for convenience
    return sorted(valid_kernels, key=lambda kernel: kernel.op)

complex_dtypes = [tf.complex64, tf.complex128]
complex_gpu_kernels = get_kernels_with_dtypes(complex_dtypes, device_type='GPU')

# Print one kernel
print(complex_gpu_kernels[0])
# op: "Add"
# device_type: "GPU"
# constraint {
#   name: "T"
#   allowed_values {
#     list {
#       type: DT_COMPLEX64
#     }
#   }
# }

# Print kernel op names
print(*(kernel.op for kernel in complex_gpu_kernels), sep='\n')
# Add
# Add
# AddN
# AddN
# AddV2
# AddV2
# Assign
# Assign
# AssignVariableOp
# AssignVariableOp
# ...
```

The problem is that you never really use ops or kernels directly when you program with TensorFlow in Python. Python functions take the arguments you give them, validate them and produce one or more new ops in the graph, typically returning the output value(s) of the last one to you. So in the end finding out what ops/kernels are relevant to you requires a bit of inspection. For example, consider the following examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Matrix multiplication: (2, 3) x (3, 4)
    tf.matmul([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
    # Print all op names and types
    all_ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
    print(*(f'Op name: {op.name}, Op type: {op.type}' for op in all_ops), sep='\n')
    # Op name: MatMul/a, Op type: Const
    # Op name: MatMul/b, Op type: Const
    # Op name: MatMul, Op type: MatMul

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Matrix multiplication: (1, 2, 3) x (1, 3, 4)
    tf.matmul([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]], [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]])
    # Print all op names and types
    all_ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
    print(*(f'Op name: {op.name}, Op type: {op.type}' for op in all_ops), sep='\n')
    # Op name: MatMul/a, Op type: Const
    # Op name: MatMul/b, Op type: Const
    # Op name: MatMul, Op type: BatchMatMul
```

Here, the same Python function [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) has produced op types in each case. The first two ops are `Const` in both cases, which result from converting the given lists to TensorFlow tensors, but the third one is `MatMul` in one case and `BatchedMatMul` in the other, because in the second case the input has one extra initial dimension.

In any case, if you can combine the approaches above to find out all the op and kernels information about one op name you are interested in:

```
def get_op_info(op_name):
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
    from tensorflow.python.framework import kernels
    reg_ops = ops.op_def_registry.get_registered_ops()
    op_def = reg_ops[op_name]
    op_kernels = list(kernels.get_registered_kernels_for_op(op_name).kernel)
    return op_def, op_kernels

# Get MatMul information
matmul_def, matmul_kernels = get_op_info('MatMul')

# Print op definition
print(matmul_def)
# name: "MatMul"
# input_arg {
#   name: "a"
#   type_attr: "T"
# }
# input_arg {
#   name: "b"
#   type_attr: "T"
# }
# output_arg {
#   name: "product"
#   type_attr: "T"
# }
# attr {
#   name: "transpose_a"
#   type: "bool"
#   default_value {
#     b: false
#   }
# }
# attr {
#   name: "transpose_b"
#   type: "bool"
#   default_value {
#     b: false
#   }
# }
# attr {
#   name: "T"
#   type: "type"
#   allowed_values {
#     list {
#       type: DT_BFLOAT16
#       type: DT_HALF
#       type: DT_FLOAT
#       type: DT_DOUBLE
#       type: DT_INT32
#       type: DT_COMPLEX64
#       type: DT_COMPLEX128
#     }
#   }
# }

# Total number of matrix multiplication kernels
print(len(matmul_kernels))
# 24

# Print one kernel definition
print(matmul_kernels[0])
# op: "MatMul"
# device_type: "CPU"
# constraint {
#   name: "T"
#   allowed_values {
#     list {
#       type: DT_FLOAT
#     }
#   }
# }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation with examples, which is really good and easy to understand for me as a beginner in tensorflow!